# Executing scripts in brunch

Tags: javascript, compilation, npm, brunch

I'm new to brunch, but I'm having trouble getting it set up properly I think. I'm using the [dead simple skeleton](https://github.com/brunch/dead-simple), and I've added a script (main.js) to the app > scripts directory, which has a simple `console.log('init');` statement in it. This compiles (I can see it in app.js), but does not execute. This is all I'm doing on the html page:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SITE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

and this is what the app.js file looks like:

```
require.register("scripts/main", function(exports, require, module) {
console.log('init');
});
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to call the script wrapper in your html by adding the require function:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SITE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script>require('app')</script>
</body>
```

Ran into the same issue very [recently](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/issues/481#issuecomment-49578665). It's just been added to the docs to be released [here](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/tree/master/docs#conventions).